# How do I get a property at index using custom validation in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have input fields in my Razor page which are loaded using a foreach loop. For example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DataList.Where(p => p.SubmittedBy == user.SubmittedBy))
{
    <input asp-for="AllTable.RefNumber" name="@item.Id" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments (optional)">
}
```

AllTable is the Model, RefNumber is the Property

I also have a custom validation class that validates the value of the textbox using this:

```
var refNumber = (string)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
```

As it stands, refNumber is null. How do I validate the field whilst retaining the unique name attribute? If I remove the unique name, it works fine but when a validation error occurs, it displays against all of the same field as the names are the same with asp-for.

Thanks,

Comment: Need clarification on the wider scope of the form. I am curious about why all those inputs will be referencing `asp-for="AllTable.RefNumber"`. Clarify what it is you are actually trying to do so the context of that loop is for is known.

Comment: Can you also include the model this form is binding to.

Comment: It's used for table row data, each row has data and underneath, another table row with a form. This form holds the RefNumber input and when clicking the approve button, will save data to database along with other hidden fields but needs to check a separate database first to ensure the ref number doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a razor page you won't be able to access the model from ObjectInstance as I don't believe it's currently supported, but the value being passed in will be your list object so.

```
    var myList = value as ApprovedList;
    var refNames = myList.Select(s => s.RefName);
```

Also, the way you are adding your inputs from the list won't allow it to bind to the model. Would need to be something like this.

```
    <input asp-for="AllTable[i].RefNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments (optional)">
```

Comment: +1 but I think the second line isn't needed; you might as well just do an explicit cast and get the same result. I'd probably do the the implicit cast and return false if it's null because it isn't the object you expected so it can't be valid. If it isn't null then continue with validation.

Comment: If I do ````var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as YourModel```` using my page model where I have my list defined, it returns null. Should I do something different with a RazorPage model?

Comment: Ah. I've had a little play around with razor pages and one of the reasons I abandoned them for usual razor view and view models is because there was no way to get access to the model in server-side validation, so you cannot do cross-field validation. I have amended my answer.